# Can I use the same field to reference two tables, which both ultimately reference the same table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization

[image]

I have designed this database to add trees to a forest, each forest is only allowed one type of tree. I want to make sure all trees added to the forest via the "forest_has_tree" table are of the correct type for that forest.

My proposed design is to have the "tree_type_idtree_type" field in the "forest_has_tree" table which references the "tree_type_idtree_type" in the "forest" table as well as the "tree_type_idtree_type" in the "tree" table (via the "tree_sub_type" table).

```
  CONSTRAINT `fk_forest_has_tree_forest1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`forest_idforest` , `tree_type_idtree_type`)
    REFERENCES `forest` (`idforest` , `tree_type_idtree_type`),
        
  CONSTRAINT `fk_forest_has_tree_tree1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tree_idtree` , `tree_tree_sub_type_idtree_sub_type` , `tree_type_idtree_type`)
    REFERENCES `tree` (`idtree` , `tree_sub_type_idtree_sub_type` , `tree_sub_type_tree_type_idtree_type`),
```

Please could anyone comment on whether this is an acceptable design, or if there is a better way of solving this problem?
I have included the full MySQL for these five tables below.

I am absolutely sure that no forest will have more than one tree type. For argument's sake let's say my forests are all run as dictatorships and if anyone were to plant an unauthorised tree they would be vaporised along with the tree, and crucially no records would be kept of it.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tree_type`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tree_type` (
  `idtree_type` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtree_type`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `forest`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forest` (
  `idforest` INT NOT NULL,
  `tree_type_idtree_type` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idforest`, `tree_type_idtree_type`),
  INDEX `fk_forest_tree_type1_idx` (`tree_type_idtree_type` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_forest_tree_type1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tree_type_idtree_type`)
    REFERENCES `tree_type` (`idtree_type`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tree_sub_type`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tree_sub_type` (
  `idtree_sub_type` INT NOT NULL,
  `tree_type_idtree_type` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtree_sub_type`, `tree_type_idtree_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tree_sub_type_tree_type1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tree_type_idtree_type`)
    REFERENCES `tree_type` (`idtree_type`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tree`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tree` (
  `idtree` INT NOT NULL,
  `tree_sub_type_idtree_sub_type` INT NOT NULL,
  `tree_sub_type_tree_type_idtree_type` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtree`, `tree_sub_type_idtree_sub_type`, `tree_sub_type_tree_type_idtree_type`),
  INDEX `fk_tree_tree_sub_type1_idx` (`tree_sub_type_idtree_sub_type` ASC, `tree_sub_type_tree_type_idtree_type` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tree_tree_sub_type1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tree_sub_type_idtree_sub_type` , `tree_sub_type_tree_type_idtree_type`)
    REFERENCES `tree_sub_type` (`idtree_sub_type` , `tree_type_idtree_type`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `forest_has_tree`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forest_has_tree` (
  `forest_idforest` INT NOT NULL,
  `tree_type_idtree_type` INT NOT NULL,
  `tree_idtree` INT NOT NULL,
  `tree_tree_sub_type_idtree_sub_type` INT NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`forest_idforest`, `tree_type_idtree_type`, `tree_idtree`, `tree_tree_sub_type_idtree_sub_type`),

  INDEX `fk_forest_has_tree_tree1_idx` (`tree_idtree` ASC, `tree_tree_sub_type_idtree_sub_type` ASC, `tree_type_idtree_type` ASC) VISIBLE,

  INDEX `fk_forest_has_tree_forest1_idx` (`forest_idforest` ASC, `tree_type_idtree_type` ASC) VISIBLE,
    
  CONSTRAINT `fk_forest_has_tree_forest1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`forest_idforest` , `tree_type_idtree_type`)
    REFERENCES `forest` (`idforest` , `tree_type_idtree_type`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
        
  CONSTRAINT `fk_forest_has_tree_tree1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tree_idtree` , `tree_tree_sub_type_idtree_sub_type` , `tree_type_idtree_type`)
    REFERENCES `tree` (`idtree` , `tree_sub_type_idtree_sub_type` , `tree_sub_type_tree_type_idtree_type`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: The primary key is forest_id.

Comment: Thank you.
I don't think I asked the question clearly.
Each 'forest' is uniquely identified by the forest_id. Each forest also has a designated tree_type, uniquely identified by tree_type_id. I need to add a 'tree' to the 'forest' via a link table, and only allow trees with the correct tree type.
Is it a sound design to have the tree_type_id in the link table referencing both the forest tree_type_id and the tree tree_type_id?

Comment: Yes, the PK is idforest : `CREATE TABLE forest
(idforest SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,tree_type_idtree_type INT NOT NULL
);`

Comment: Rearranging tables for subtypes/supertypes is not database normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Tree type TYP exists.
--
 tree_type {TYP}
        PK {TYP}
```

```
-- Tree sub-type SUB of tree type TYP exists.
--
 tree_sub {TYP, SUB}
       PK {TYP, SUB}

FK {TYP} REFERENCES tree_type {TYP}
```

```
-- Tree TRE is of tree type TYP, sub-type SUB.
--
 tree {TRE, TYP, SUB}
   PK {TRE}
   SK {TRE, TYP}

FK {TYP, SUB} REFERENCES tree_sub {TYP, SUB}
```

```
-- Forest FOR has only trees of type TYP.
--
forest {FOR, TYP}
    PK {FOR}
    SK {FOR, TYP}

FK {TYP} REFERENCES tree_type {TYP}
```

*Each* tree is part of *at most one* forest.

```
-- Tree TRE, of tree type TYP, is part of forest FOR.
--
forest_has_tree {TRE, TYP, FOR}
             PK {TRE}

FK1 {TRE, TYP} REFERENCES tree   {TRE, TYP}
FK2 {FOR, TYP} REFERENCES forest {FOR, TYP}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: Yes, this is an almost identical solution to the one I proposed.
You have kept my design of using two references on the same attribute to ensure that only trees of the correct type are added to a forest, so in answer to my question of "Is that a sound design?" I am taking your answer as a "Yes"
By using the tree id TRE as the PK for the forest_has_tree table you've changed the many-to-many relationship into a one-to-many relationship: each tree can only belong to one forest. I actually do want a many-to-many relationship but that isn't relevant to the question about foreign keys.

Comment: @DuncanConnolly, Yes if a tree can be part of more than one forest then `PK` of `forest_has_tree` is `{FOR, TRE}`.

Comment: @DuncanConnolly, DB is supposed to be a sound and closed logical system. When an attribute is defined, say `tree_id` than that name means the same thing, and is of the same type, everywhere in the DB. For some reason you seem to be changing names from table to table. Also take note of `PKs` on `forest` and `tree`.

Comment: Yes good advice, my naming was generated automatically by MySQL Workbench, to include the referenced table name as well as the attribute name but that is very confusing so I will change it to follow better naming conventions.
So basically if I understand your answer correctly, my original design had unnecessary  primary keys, and poor naming conventions, but the concept of having two foreign key constraints on a single attribute is okay as long as it "means the same thing, and is of the same type, everywhere in the DB"

Comment: @DuncanConnolly; Admittedly, only now do I understand what you were really asking.
A constraint is a *Boolean expression*. If that expression evaluates
to `FALSE` (at any time) the DB should raise an error. That's it. You can have as many as you want, referencing whatever you want. Just make sure it makes sense; constraints stem from logic and "business rules". Loosely speaking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your schema only requires the following (FK constraints and surrogate ids omitted for brevity)...

EDITED TO ADD A WORKED EXAMPLE...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trees;

CREATE TABLE trees
(tree_group VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,species VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO trees VALUES
('Alder','Alnus glutinosa'),
('Ash','Fraxinus excelsior'),
('Birch','Downy Birch'),
('Birch','Silver Birch'),
('Birch','Betula pendula'),
('Cherry','Bird Cherry'),
('Cherry','Wild Cherry'),
('Cherry','Prunus avium'),
('Elm','English Elm'),
('Elm','Wych Elm'),
('Hawthorn','Hawthorn'),
('Hawthorn','Midland Hawthorn'),
('Holly','Ilex aquifolium'),
('Oak','Common Oak'),
('Oak','Sessile Oak'),
('Oak','Quercus petraea'),
('Poplar','Black Poplar'),
('Poplar','Aspen Poplar'),
('Poplar','Populus tremula'),
('Pine','Pinus sylvestris'),
('Pine','Douglas Fir');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS forest;

CREATE TABLE forest
(forest_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,tree_group VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO forest VALUES
('poplar_forest1','Poplar'),
('poplar_forest2','Poplar'),
('cherry_forest1','Cherry'),
('cherry_forest2','Cherry');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS forest_tree;

CREATE TABLE forest_tree
(forest_name VARCHAR(50)
,species VARCHAR(50)
,PRIMARY KEY(forest_name,species)
);

SELECT * FROM trees;
+------------+--------------------+
| tree_group | species            |
+------------+--------------------+
| Alder      | Alnus glutinosa    |
| Poplar     | Aspen Poplar       |
| Birch      | Betula pendula     |
| Cherry     | Bird Cherry        |
| Poplar     | Black Poplar       |
| Oak        | Common Oak         |
| Pine       | Douglas Fir        |
| Birch      | Downy Birch        |
| Elm        | English Elm        |
| Ash        | Fraxinus excelsior |
| Hawthorn   | Hawthorn           |
| Holly      | Ilex aquifolium    |
| Hawthorn   | Midland Hawthorn   |
| Pine       | Pinus sylvestris   |
| Poplar     | Populus tremula    |
| Cherry     | Prunus avium       |
| Oak        | Quercus petraea    |
| Oak        | Sessile Oak        |
| Birch      | Silver Birch       |
| Cherry     | Wild Cherry        |
| Elm        | Wych Elm           |
+------------+--------------------+

SELECT * FROM forest;
+----------------+------------+
| forest_name    | tree_group |
+----------------+------------+
| cherry_forest1 | Cherry     |
| cherry_forest2 | Cherry     |
| poplar_forest1 | Poplar     |
| poplar_forest2 | Poplar     |
+----------------+------------+

SET NAMES utf8;

TRUNCATE forest_tree;

SET @forest_name = 'poplar_forest1';
SET @species = 'Populus tremula';

INSERT IGNORE INTO forest_tree (forest_name,species) 
SELECT @forest_name 
     , @species
  FROM forest f 
  JOIN trees t 
    ON t.tree_group = f.tree_group 
 WHERE forest_name = @forest_name
   AND species = @species
 LIMIT 1;
 
 SELECT * FROM forest_tree;
  +----------------+-----------------+
  | forest_name    | species         |
  +----------------+-----------------+
  | poplar_forest1 | Populus tremula |
  +----------------+-----------------+
 
 SET @forest_name = 'poplar_forest1';
 SET @species = 'Black Cherry';
 
 INSERT IGNORE INTO forest_tree (forest_name,species)
 SELECT @forest_name
      , @species
   FROM forest f
   JOIN trees t
     ON t.tree_group = f.tree_group
  WHERE forest_name = @forest_name
    AND species = @species
  LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM forest_tree;
  +----------------+-----------------+
  | forest_name    | species         |
  +----------------+-----------------+
  | poplar_forest1 | Populus tremula |
  +----------------+-----------------+

SET @forest_name = 'poplar_forest1';
SET @species = 'Populus tremula';

INSERT IGNORE INTO forest_tree (forest_name,species)
SELECT @forest_name
     , @species
  FROM forest f
  JOIN trees t
    ON t.tree_group = f.tree_group
 WHERE forest_name = @forest_name
   AND species = @species
 LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM forest_tree;
  +----------------+-----------------+
  | forest_name    | species         |
  +----------------+-----------------+
  | poplar_forest1 | Populus tremula |
  +----------------+-----------------+

SET @forest_name = 'poplar_forest1';
SET @species = 'Black Poplar';

INSERT IGNORE INTO forest_tree (forest_name,species)
SELECT @forest_name
     , @species
  FROM forest f
  JOIN trees t
    ON t.tree_group = f.tree_group
 WHERE forest_name = @forest_name
   AND species = @species
 LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM forest_tree;
+----------------+-----------------+
| forest_name    | species         |
+----------------+-----------------+
| poplar_forest1 | Black Poplar    |
| poplar_forest1 | Populus tremula |
+----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: This schema effectively combines the 'tree' table with the 'forest_has_tree' table. This would create a problem that now a 'tree' can only be a member of one 'forest', although 'forest' would still be able to have many 'trees'.

By ommitting FK constraints this answer avoids answering the actual question which is specifically about FK constraints.

The question specifies that the 'forest_has_tree' table has a field 'tree_type_idtree_type' with two FK constraints - referencing two tables, and asks if this is a sound design.

Comment: There is no such limitation here. It seems an unsound design to me, because it appears to have redundancy